# Arrangement if $3$ boys and $2$ girls in a Queue

Tags: combinatorics

$3$ Boys and $2$ Girls are arranged  in a queue. Then the number of ways in which number of Boys ahead of every Girl is at least one more then the number of Girls ahead of her,is

Let B : Boy and G : Girl

Here queue from Left to Right.

Then we have

$GBBGB$

$GGBBB$

$BBGBB$

But answer given is $5$

Please have a look on that problem

Thanks

Comment: Please check , you have given one wrong sequence .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clarifying answer that should help you understand the process to come up with this:

We begin with placing a boy at the front of the line, as starting with a girl means we would fail no matter what:
$$XXXXB$$

For spot two, we can choose a boy or a girl, it doesn't matter. But, for spot 3, if we chose girl for two, we need boy for three (as $XXGGB$ is failing). If we chose boy for two we can choose either boy or girl for three. Our combinations are now:

$$XXBGB \\ XXGBB \\ XXBBB$$
Now we consider each case individually. For the first case, we can put a girl in either spot, and a boy in either spot, as both work. For the second, we can  also do one in both. But for the third, we only have $2$ girls left, so we have $1$ more combination. Thus our $5$ combinations are:
$$GBBGB \\\ BGBGB \\ BGGBB \\\ GBGBB \\ GGBBB$$
We also know there are no other legal combinations, since we ruled out every other possible combination. Hence we have 5. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let the boys be represented as ${B}$ and girls as $G$. Then the number of ways are

$GGBBB$,
$GBGBB$,
$BGBGB$,
$GBBGB$ and $BGGBB$. Note here all the *B*’s AND *G*’s are distinct (we cannot have $3$ same boys, they have to be different). For any girl with another girl in front of it she must have two boys in front of her. For any girl with no other girl in front of her she must have atleast one boy in front of her.